# How to Copy and Paste from One TextBox to another TextBox on the Same Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to copy values from one textbox to another textbox when user clicks a button. It seems to be a simple solution but for some reason when I click the coppyButton1 on the form, the value from uid1 (TextBox1) not getting copied into uid2(TextBox2). Hoping for feedback.

Code:

```
private void copyButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     uid2.Text = uid1.Text;
}
```

Comment: _Technically_ that's not copy-paste, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.  Are you sure the event is attached to button's `Click` event in the properties window?

Comment: No reason why this shouldn't work, assuming the `Name` properties are correct, and the `copyButton1` is also correct..

Comment: I build a sample `WindowsForm` app, with 2 `TextBox` controls called `ui1` and `ui2`, and a button with the same code and the app works fine!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.Yes, you all are right, when I used the same code on a simple form away from the one with other controls, it works fine, but for some reason in the form with other controls it is not working. I will check the form more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate data to the clipboard incredibly easy:

```
Clipboard.SetText(txtCopyText.Text);
```

That would take the value of the textbox, then store to the clipboard.

```
protected void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // You would want to validate the contents of the textbox before copying.

     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCopy.Text))
          Clipboard.SetText(txtCopy.Text);          
}
```

If you simply want to force the value from one field to another, then the code you have above would force the value to be set.  But to apply to the clipboard for copy and paste, you would do the above.

The only reason that code might not work would be if you don't have the textbox instantiated, or those fields are on another form that deviates from your `btnCopy`.  Or you tabbed and allowed intellisense to reverse your copied data, ie one vs two.  Your code:

```
ui2.Text = ui1.Text;
```

Is the field you thought you were copying from `ui1.Text`?

---

**Update**

To get data from the clipboard, you would do the following:

```
if(Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
     txtPaste.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks Greg for your feedback. The field I am trying to copy from is uid1.Text. I tried to use the Clipboard feature like below but that didn't work: if(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) == true) { if(uid1.SelectionLength > 0)
                {
                    uid2.SelectionStart = uid1.SelectionStart + uid1.SelectionLength;
                    uid2.Paste();
                }
           }

Comment: I'm using the same form. How do I instantiate textbox? The form is working for other controls including reading the values from various textbox and processing it for other tasks, but it is not copying from one textbox to another on the same form.My understanding was that InitializeComponent() plays a role along with Form1_Load function instantiating all the necessary objects. Please correct me on this if misunderstood.

Comment: Hi Greg, I'm trying to use the example code you've shown. How do I set uid2.Text with value obtained from Clipboard.SetText(uid1.Text)?

Comment: @mkarim Answered for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now, it is working. I have done the following:         private void copy_button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(uid1.Text);
            uid2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();  }